# Friction between two objects accelerating in different directions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

I have a question regarding Coulomb friction.

Assume we have two blocks stacked on top of each other. The bottom block lies in a perfectly smooth surface (so no friction). Assume static coefficient of friction between the two blocks of 0.4 and kinetic of 0.3. Towards the positive x-axis a force of 5N is acting on the bottom block. In the opposite direction a force of 5N is acting on the top. Both blocks have a mass of 2kg.

Now when considering whether the two objects will start slipping relative to each other, do I have to consider both forces as if acting on the same body (but the force from the other object acting in the opposite direction of what it is). Because while 5N alone may not be enough, the two forces acting in different directions should be enough to break static friction